# Ubuntu Gnome freezing during startup

Tags: boot, gnome, startup, 15.04, acpi

This morning I installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.04.  I installed a few applications and restarted the computer a couple times without issue.  I just ran updates though, and when I restarted the computer after updates were finished, the computer hangs at the splash screen with all three dots filled.

Ctrl+Shift+Num Keys does nothing, same with Ctrl+Alt+Del.

The only thing that works to make the computer do something is pressing the power button.  The screen will flash the output text from startup.  The last two things I see are:

```
Starting GNOME Display Manager
gdm.service
```

The text flashes, then it goes back to the splash screen, no longer frozen, then the computer shuts down.  I am able to boot from the linux usb drive that I used to install Ubuntu, but am not sure which logs to look at or how to move forward.

UPDATE:
Found the boot.log file these are the last few entries:

```
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Restore Sound Card State.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Permit User Sessions.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand".
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down..
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Console System Startup Logging.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Ubuntu live CD installer.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Bluetooth service.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started System Logging Service.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Bluetooth.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
         Starting Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Login Service.
         Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Accounts Service.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Modem Manager.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Manager.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
         Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
         Starting MySQL Community Server...
         Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
         Starting Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit...
         Starting WPA supplicant...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started WPA supplicant.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
         Starting GNOME Display Manager...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started GNOME Display Manager.
```

If I start in recovery mode, it gives me options for recover, I select continue boot.  I receive a message saying that some display manager won't work after recovery boot, that a restart might be necessary.  I say continue, then it freezes at a blank screen.  I push the power button once, it flashes to a terminal with login prompt and then restarts.
I've also tried going into recovery mode and repairing packages with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe related with this bug?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1460045

I've got that issue with Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 after upgrading to Gnome 3.16 (in 3.14 version my laptop works ok).

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't think I'm having the same issue as I do not have an nvidia graphics card. I was however able to get to a login prompt. I'm going to try to figure out how to revert back to GDM 3.14

Comment: One of the things that I was told to do was to install lightdm instead of GDM. You could try this too.

-Install the Lightdm desktop display manager typing: 

sudo apt-get install lightdm

-During installation you will be asked about what manager do you want (gdm or lightdm). Choose "lightdm".

-Reboot

If you need (or want) to change the lightdm for gdm, you only have to type:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot, I did read that going back to 3.14 is no help as certain apps will no longer work properly.

Comment: Switching to lightdm works for now.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped you in anyway.

Comment: This worked for me, but there is the detail missing of getting to a location where you can run the necessary commands. FOr those that don't know, Ctrl-Alt-F1 can get you a terminal if it seems to freeze at the display loading step. Further, if it says lightdm is already installed, you can run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to get the configuration screen that lets you choose it as the default display manager