# GUI does not start

Tags: boot, gnome

[image: picture of error]

Initially, the computer was showing the error as mentioned in  [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/q/141606) question. Fixing it resulted in the above error.

Please take look at the last line

```
Started GNOME display manager... and deal with any system changes..p link was shut down.....
```

---

One more thing before all this problem I have edited xorg.conf file to use [Tooya X graphic tablet](https://askubuntu.com/q/638712/283650) as suggested on [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1103792.).

I don't know if that's the reason but I thought it is important to share.

Comment: I can see no error there. How long did you leave it for?

Comment: For about 2 hours. @Tim

Comment: Hmm okay. It's strange because there is no obvious error.

Comment: @Tim any suggestions that I can try?

Comment: I'm really no expert in these things I'm afraid...

Comment: There are 38 fixes in that link... Which one did you use?

Comment: @Fabby I have tried this http://askubuntu.com/a/173238/283650

Comment: x-server errors are way above my competency level...

Comment: Try pressing various combination of Ctrl+Alt+Fkey. Ubuntu gui is typically on F7, other F keys are virtual terminals.  Also Alt+arrow left/right. I think 15.04 on my other laptop had similar issue

Comment: @Serg Ctrl + Alt + F 1-6 opens virtual terminal while Cltrl + Alt + F7 returns back to black screen shown in question.

Comment: Ok can you start xserver manually ? Login to Ctrl+Alt+F1. Run either `startx` ( you may need to press alt + left / right ) or `sudo service lightdm restart`. The fact that you have virtual terminal access is good - means we can work on possible fixes

Comment: @Serg Using `sudo service lightdm restart ` shows following message `Job for lightdm.service failed. See "systemct1 status lightdm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details`

Comment: The comment I wrote is too large so had to post on pastebin. http://paste.ubuntu.com/11797066/    it's impossible to get a lot done on mobile :(

Comment: @Serg I think it will be easy if we use chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25340/room-for-freddy-and-serg

Comment: Since when does Ubuntu use `systemd`? Why does it suggest you do `systemctl status lightdm.service` unless you're running `systemd`?

Comment: @codingman as of 15.04 Ubuntu's switching to systemd. It came with his ubuntu version by default

Comment: I had the same issue and before you reset the whole system please try reinstall the nvidia drivers and look in the xorg.conf file if the driver is commended out. I'm not sure if you need to do the first part, but it worked for me.

Comment: In 20.04 I occasionally removed python3 through `apt` and got no GUI as a result. `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall --fix-missing` fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried all the possible solutions mentioned in comment area and other answers. Unfortunately none of them work.

Solution that worked for me was **format and re-install**.

I had to format my laptop before re-installing. Because re-installing without format was not working. I mean computer starts normally but there were several bugs with WiFi, Bluetooth, USB, etc.

Comment: i happen to get this issue as well, did you get it again?.. i want to be really sure if it doesn't happen again in post-format and re-install, otherwise. it wouldn't be worth it

Comment: @nosthertus It's like a year...till now all working fine.

Comment: format and re-install  sure will work. You will probably loose previous experience on your system and a  very good chance to improve your knowledge.

Answer (score 62):

Alt+F2 keystroke which started the terminal session for me and I was able to login.

```
sudo apt purge gdm gdm3
sudo apt install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop
```

Then choose your display manager in the menu that opens (for Ubuntu 16.10+ the default is GDM, for 16.04 and earlier the default is LightDM), or use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` to choose GDM.

```
systemctl restart gdm
```

This should work

Comment: `systemctl restart gdm` really helps me with ubuntu 18.04, thanks)

Comment: I panicked when only the Ubuntu login showed up during login. Your guide saved me! Thank you!

Comment: This resolved things for me after not being able to boot into the gdm gui after updating from 22.04 to 22.10, seeing "Gdm: GdmSession: no session desktop files installed, aborting..." . Thanks!

NOTE: I had to do this by normal boot, getting stuck in the console then ctrl+alt+f2 to get into tty2 to run the above. Even had to switch keyboards.

Answer (score 9):

There appears to be [other people](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631063/ubuntu-gnome-freezing-during-startup) having this issue as well. A [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1460045) was also made on this. It appears to be a bug with version 3.16. A temporary fix would be to use LightDM instead, so (in a VT, eg `Ctrl+Alt+F1`:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Press enter to get past the "Configuring lightdm" screen, and then navigate to LightDM in the list of options and press Enter. Restart, and you should be using LightDM. This should work temporarily until the GDM bug is fixed.

Comment: Does not work :(

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to _what_ doesn't work?

Comment: This worked for me. I also `apt remove gdm3`, although not sure if it was necessary.

Comment: Your solution worked for me thank you same my linux :)

Comment: I'm using Dell latitude 5580 and had similar issue time to time, formatted few times but the issues comes. This one worked for me and this only. Thanks a lot for saving my time.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue like this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>
3. Log in via terminal
4. Go to `/etc/X11` and delete `xorg.conf` (or rename for backup)

Comment: I have the same issue, but for me `xorg.conf` just absent in the `/etc/X11`

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue, After messing around for 3-4 hours I finally got the ubuntu running.

Before I reboot the ubuntu I did install xubuntu by

`sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

and then I did

`mkdir -p /var/lib/lightdm`

`chown -R lightdm:lightdm /var/lib/lightdm`

`chmod 0750 /var/lib/lightdm`

So it installed xubuntu desktop but I got everything working fine.

This is how I did it.

I would suggest first try the 2nd part if that does not work then try the installing xubuntu desktop.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thank you, it works for my case.

Answer (score 2):

Happened with me with gdm 3.28. The problem was nvidia driver (which was working fine few days before) After allowing software updater to install updates I shut it down and rebooted in morning to see this same error.

Solution:

Uninstalled nvidia driver (I used the .run file to install it)

Press Alt+F3 to access console mode

```
sudo nvidia-uninstall
shutdown now
```

Verdict: Do not update software from GUI if you have nvidia driver installed. Check if the update will affect any installed driver, especially if the driver isn't from ubuntu repositories

Answer (score 1):

Enter a TTY with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and run:

```
sudo apt-get install LXDE
```

Then execute

```
startx
```

and then push start button left corner and the preferencs and the upper gfx settings adm and set all to default, and reboot and it might work fine this way.

Answer (score 1):

You will get more details when running gdm manually in a virtual console (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1`):

```
sudo gdm
```

For me, the problem was that gdm wasn't able to find /usr/bin/X, which led me to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/737651). Turns out xserver-xorg was not installed somehow. The following line solves this particular problem.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with Ubuntu 17.10 in a Virtualbox VM the error occurred because the partition for Linux was full. I solved this problem this way:

1. Start the machine with using Linux live image (on CD, USB or so)
2. Mount the Linux partition and create space
3. Restart the machine

Answer (score 1):

Start Ubuntu in recovery mode, (Esc->Advanced options->recovery mode).
You have few things to check and correct, in particular my issue was solved after selecting and passing tow entries [dppk: repair broken packages], some upgrades where done and some obsolete packages removed. then i check entry: [**grub**: update grub **bootloader**] ... something was corrected! then i chose to boot ... then system boots normally! my point is if you can boot in recovery and check your `fs` ...etc. then no need to format/install.