# Stuck in boot After installing graphics driver

Tags: software-installation

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

After I have used these commands, I restart my pc but it shows the below message :

> started GNOME display manager. Dispatcher service... system changes.pp
>   link was shut down.

I had to wait 1 hour and restart using power button but it shows the same message . What should I do to fix this problem ?

System conf : **Ubuntu 18.04**

Graphics    :  **Amd radeon r5**

Comment: When I use Ctrl +Alt+F2 ,then no login command line show.

Comment: How can I get login command line , there is any another way,  because this  (Ctrl +Alt+F2 ) is not working in my PC,

Comment: Now I have done using  Ctrl+Alt+F4, but problem has occurred.new message shows. UBUNTU :clean, 273917/59785216 files, 24845812/239123200 blocks

Comment: Actually I am unable to do anything, please can you tell me step by step. what I should to do, for look my PC as previous. Now my screen show black. etc/apt/sources.list.d to remove the ppa you added. Then use apt to try to downgrade the packages you updated

Comment: I use your code then ( -bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d: is a directory) now what I should to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Machine does not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/machine-does-not-start)

Answer (score 0):

What most likely happen is that you are trying to use [oibaf/graphics-driversdriver which is for x-org](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_1310_oibaf&num=1), but you are running Wayland with then new Gnome3. The reason gnome isn't working is that the drivers changed to using aren't right for Gnome. Stopped using X.org and now uses Wayland. X.org is the program that lets the Linux kernel access your monitor. X.org is really old, and has a lot of problems because in the time it's been around for a long as it has. When it was first made it was for very different technology compared to what we are using now and had to changed to accommodate more modern technology. Don't get me wrong, most end users really shouldn't notice a difference between X.org or Wayland. Wayland is new and was developed to be a replacement for X.org.

**In short, you are using the wrong driver.** But that's good because now we can change it back to the old driver. If you can get a command line after boot, and log in, you then want to uninstall the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

Then run to clean up the system:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then restart the computer:

```
sudo reboot
```

If the problem persists, when you upgraded you system after changing the PPA something else was changed in the upgrade that is causing this problem.

Comment: Now screen shown black

Comment: I think there is no solution for this ,  if I restore Ubuntu 16.04 to factory state  then problem will solve or not?

Comment: You can reinstall Ubuntu, and if it was working before, it should work again. However, since you're trying to use PPAs, presumably to use more updated software, you should consider using 18.04.