# GUI not starting and no access to VT

Tags: gui

I am running ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Latitude 6420. After having some issues playing videos online, I rebooted and obtained the same problem as the one listed here:
[GUI does not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start)

The additional problem is that in my case, I am unable to access any virtual terminal. I have tried Alt-F1 to F12 and Ctrl-Alt-F1 to F12. Any other option?

Comment: The article you link is a bit all over the place, some of the commands they ask you to run would probably cause issues on your system. Boot into recovery as per kc1di's recommendations then undo any changes you might have made in `/etc/X11/` or `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. Also make sure that `gdm3`, `ubuntu-desktop` and `xserver-xorg-video-intel` are still installed on your system by run `apt install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop xserver-xorg-video-intel` and see how far you get after this.

Comment: I booted in recovery mode and ran the "clean" option. After that, the system was able to load the GUI. Noticing that my root partition was getting close to full, I then rebooted on gparted-live and expanded the partition. This solved the issue. FYI, my graphics is listed as Intel Sandybridge Mobile in Ubuntu-Settings. Thank you kc1di and fmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get to a root terminal in the recovery mode boot.  by following the instructions [here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

The problem is often one of the video driver. Do you know which card your machine has?