# New computer from Dell with pre-installed Ubuntu won't boot. Should I assume it's an error from Dell?

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia, dell

I bought a new computer, a precision tower 7920 with Quadro RTX 4000 GPUs. Because the nvidia driver installation is so complicated, I ordered the machine with Ubuntu (as it was supported by Dell and comes pre-installed).

However from the very first time I turned the computer on it won't boot, getting stuck at

```
Starting Gnome Display Manager
```

showing no error messages, but not moving forward from that point. Just like in this question:
[GUI does not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start)

It looks like the graphic drivers aren't installed properly. I could start debugging this. But my concern is: **Should I even consider that Dell would send a new computer that is incapable of booting?** Is this an 'exchange the product' case?

Comment: Fully agree with @Karel here, it is Dell's reponsiblity to provide a usable computer. So it is entirely their fault. I would recommend not allowing them to "troubleshoot" for you because most of the time support staff are not trained in Linux support, and often have no clue what they are doing.

Comment: You may want to boot from a live Ubuntu media just to confirm for yourself that the hardware is fine.

Comment: Returning/fixing will take weeks; you may want to fiddle a bit before you do that. As a matter of terminology: The machine clearly *does* boot (the system must be up and running in order to start a GUI). You may want to determine whether the machine actually hangs overall or whether just the GUI startup hangs; for that, try to switch to a different console with Alt+Function key (I think any except F7 because that's where X is running). If starting the GUI makes it hang overall try to start in single user mode to a text console and examine the log files.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Agreed, however it doesn't need to take weeks. The OP is fully entitled to request a refund instead of a replacement. He can purchase a new PC simultaneously.

Comment: Technically, it did boot if it shows "starting gnome display manager" :) Sounds like unsupported, misconfigured (BIOS settings) or confused (wrong head) graphics hardware

Comment: Does ALT+F1 dump you to a console login screen?

Comment: It shouldn't take weeks. I don't know Dell's policies, but most reputable vendors in this situation will say "we're very sorry, we're shipping out a replacement today and here's an RMA tag to send back the non-working one." Your time is worth money, and you should not spend your time to fix their problem.

Comment: @rackandboneman nope, no response to any keyboard combination, can't get into any virtual terminal. I solved it already (comment on the accepted response), but my issue was more about which strategy to follow: debug or return

Comment: Please make a point of getting a working computer. Dell is know to gimp their offers with linux preinstalled.

Comment: I've been looking at getting a Dell pre-installed with Ubuntu and this is an interesting question - please keep us updated with the end result and how/when Dell replies/fixes the issue!

Comment: @BruceWayne I solved the issue myself (at least so far), turns out it was an easy fix (see comment on karel) but it involved a full day of debugging. Technical support was reachable and friendly but could not help at all. I am still waiting to be contacted by a dell engineer.

Comment: @RussellBorogove It sounds like you've had experience with different vendors to me. In the mid-late 2000s, any replacement hardware Apple sent out was "refurbished" - in other words, something that had been returned to them as faulty and that they *claimed* to have now adequately repaired. You usually had to go through a long process culminating in erasing your HD and reinstalling OS X before they'd even consider that. Luckily, customers who'd brought from bricks-and-mortar stores could return them there. Apple took the position that their guarantee extended only to the HW, not the SW.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You don't have to accept a computer that doesn't boot from Dell or from anyone. If the computer has a guarantee, return it and make them honor their guarantee. If you do too many things to try to repair this computer, it may be used as an excuse to void the guarantee, and you'll be stuck with a useless unbootable computer.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your reply, but personally I would consider first checking logs or reinstalling the OS myself. Taking the computer back to the store and then waiting for diagnostics/fix will take much more time.

Comment: A fresh OS is nice if you end up taking the computer back to the store anyway. If you tamper with it the store may reinstall Ubuntu from their own Ubuntu iso. The problem is all they have at the store is an old Ubuntu 12.04 CD, so they will reinstall Ubuntu from that for test purposes. That's not exactly fair if there's an issue with the guarantee, because it makes a simple matter too complicated for me . Otherwise they will hopefully keep it simple and test with the Ubuntu OS which is already installed.

Comment: @karel I tried with some small fixes and one solved the issue (diabling the Wayland display server and forcing the system to use Xorg). Still I think the correct move is to expect a working computer and should not fiddle around it. I just have now concerns on quality check on their side and wondered if exchanging the machine would have solved anything. But I see that your approach should be the correct one.

Comment: Presumably OP just purchased this recently, in which case he can rely on sale of goods laws rather than any guarantee. Most countries will have such a rule whereby within a certain period (e.g. 30 days) you can return a faulty product for a full refund, regardless of any guarantee (or lack thereof).

Comment: @Maadinsh you should first read small print, as stupid as it sound, reinstalling the OS yourself might void the guarantee even for hardware ...

Comment: In the US, reinstalling a computer's OS or installing a different OS won't void the warranty. Warranties are covered by federal law, and companies cannot enforce warranty requirements that violate the law.

Answer (score 23):

You *could* boot off a flash drive and nuke the existing OS installation since it seems to only be a software issue but, as others have said, it is Dell's responsibility and you should file a warranty claim.

Comment: This was my original thought as well

Comment: If the OP had just got the computer, a return to retailer should be used instead of a warranty claim. Only submit a warranty claim if the retailer won't exchange or refund.

Comment: Reinstalling the OS is likely less hassle than returning it and being without a laptop for some time.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the what everyone else said, there's also the very distinct possibility that there's a hardware problem. Definitely contact Dell.

Answer (score 2):

What did you buy? Some hardware, or a working computer (with the knowledge that Linux is well supported on it)?

What are your skills? Are you fluent enough on Linux to be able to reinstall some Linux distro on your computer without any help? Are you capable of detecting most hardware issues?

How much is your time worth? Can you wait a week to get that problem fixed, or do you prefer to fix it yourself because you actually have some work to do quickly with that computer? You'll probably lose nearly a week (in practice) to get that problem fixed by Dell. Of course, it *will* be fixed.

The latest Ubuntu is 19.04 now. You might have reasons to prefer the latest distro, not the most stable one (or vice versa). I prefer, as a developer, to have the latest libraries.

I've got the same workstation at work (but right now, in mid-August 2019, I am on vacation) and I preferred to reinstall Debian on it.

> Should I even consider that Dell would send a new computer that is incapable of booting?

We are sadly living in a world where capital (and shareholders' interests) is more important (and more valuable) than labor. The poor guy actually *installing* Ubuntu at Dell's factory is probably underpaid, even more than you or me are. He made some mistake, but that happens to all of us...

[*Errare humanum est*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/errare_humanum_est), but the most interesting part comes next.