# Ubuntu is not opening. Shows this screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 19.04

Out of nowhere, my Ubuntu system stopped opening. I have dual booted it along with Windows 10, which also stopped opening on installing updated drivers from the DELL website yesterday. Upon booting I get this screen:

[image: error image]

This screen remains for as long as I don't do something externally, like power off or something.

The lines in white are different sometimes, but, almost all of the times, the last one is `pp link was shut down`, as shown in the picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GUI does not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)