# I start the operating system and it waits (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04

I start my computer and window open this. i don´t know what do with this.I wait for very time without that load.

that happenes after that installed the drivers of nvidia the next url:https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Installing-drivers.

also, me card is de intel and not nvidia.

[image: .04]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GUI does not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start)

Answer (score 0):

hello guys i have solution for that problem.

enter next filed: /lib/systemd/system
  uses next comand: vi dnsmasq.service

and add next

```
after=network-online.target
wants=network-online.target
```

in cli run next comand:
  1- systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.
  2- systemctl enable dnsmasq.service.
  3- systemctl start dnsmasq.service.
    3.1) last comand you have problem use next comand for configurate dns
          curl -l https://install.pihole.net | bash