# Ubuntu 20.04 UI doesn't come up

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

While I upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 LTS, it got stuck with the message upon reboot:

```
Starting Hostname Service ...er..Rate Color Profiles...Stem changes.pp link was shut down...
```

[image]

Comment: This question has been asked before and already has an answer.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start