# No GUI after installing it on ubuntu server

Tags: server, gui

I installed ubuntu-desktop on 20.04 server, but there's no gui, tried both gdm3 and lightdm, tried this https://askubuntu.com/a/1013870 and still no changes.

[image: that's all i get on screen]

Comment: What do you see when you run **startx** in the console?