# Ubuntu Stuck at Screen with OK screen

Tags: boot

Heyo, so I have this ubuntu desktop that was working fine. I decided to install Steam on it and Skyrim. Apparently Steam has compatibility modes for Linux which is cool. Anyways I think it bricked my Linux install which is wierd.

It worked fine in running it but the restarting now is wrecked. I can't start the system like. It gets stuck at **[ OK ] Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles..proxy server..**

The keyboard doesn't seem to work...

Here's the image of the screen. This website wouldn't let me link it.
https://pasteboard.co/Ji1uBkC.jpg

HALP PLZ

Comment: Did you try booting into recovery mode with some previous kernels?

Did you try `Alt + f2` or `ctrl + alt + f2` for opening a terminal?

You can also check out [this page on archlinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224885) which tells you how to get the boot log, I think that can help you move forward, if you are facing difficulties in solving, you can just paste the relevant section of the boot log here.
The problem I guess is mainly of the `colord.service`.

Comment: Yeah I went into recovery mode... the TTY is kinda glitchy. I think when it tried to install DirectX automatically it fucked my GDM3. Not sure but been messing around uninstalling and what not and now I get different errors with the GNOME Display Manager. Going to try switching to LightDM

Comment: Yeah, many other answers on this topic was pointing to corruption of GDM3. Before switching to lightdm, I suggest you  try to reinstall GDM3 using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start) thread.

Comment: Thanks! Switching to lightdm worked. I will have to give GDM3 another shot. Since corona virus has killed socializing I will probably end up spending some decompression time playing this game. My main concern is that it will damage gdm3 again. Is there any specific advantage in performance of games in gdm3 vs lightdm. I have to figure out how to get some decent FPS. I think it related to incorrect nvidia drivers :/

Comment: Yes, its better to give gdm3 another try since it is the main display manager and in the latest version of 20.04  they have fixed almost all the issues with nvidia. Better to check some forums to see why Steam app has this behaviour ( I have no clue, I do not use Steam app on ubuntu ). I also was not able to find much  info on these drivers with respect to gamin ( better to open a new question on this lol ). Also why you do not game on Windows instead?

Comment: Also you should post your solution to this question of switching to lightdm as your answer ( better if you explain some steps also ), it will help a lot of people.

Comment: I will when i have the exact steps ironed out. I am in the process of figuring out the issue in gdm3. But yes switching to lightdm has been helpful... im working out if the official nvidia drivers have a an issue with multiple displays and gdm3

Answer (score 2):

So it would seem that installing a game via Steam using the compatibility tool reconfigured my gdm3 in a way that was absolutely broken on reboot.

Please note that my nvidia linux drivers were not installed. That may have contributed to the issue.

> The quick fix was switching to lightdm. The longer fix is apt-get
> purge 'nvidia*', uninstalling gdm3, reinstalling gdm3, reinstalling
> the nvidia drivers. This fixed it and now my visuals are snappy and
> fast.

I prefer gdm3 to lightdm aesthetically. I think I would only run lightdm on a low spec machine or microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this behavior of Steam is new to me. Glad it got fixed though, kudos to you!