# Must do Ctrl Alt F1 to be able to start graphical session

Tags: login, gui, gdm

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 using a mini iso. I added gnome-session firefox and some other things.

For some reason, when starting the PC I only get a black screen. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> I see the GNOME login screen. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd> shows a line that reads `dev/sda9 clean`... (sda9 is the ext4 partition where I installed the system)

I'm sure I'm missing something. I'm quite inexperienced with the command line.

Hope someone can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: You could try looking at the solutions posted <a href="https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start">here</a>.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I ended up installing lightdm. Changed it to look more like gdm and Im very happy with the result.