# GUI does not start and forgotten login

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 18.04, gui

I have this issue [GUI does not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start).

To solve it, I have to use terminal using Alt+F2. However it demands login and password to take actions in terminal.

I forgot my login.

Any ideas?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   You've tagged multiple releases which makes no sense currently.

Comment: If you have forgotten your login, how do you normally log in to gui ?

Comment: @guiverc I am using 18.04 .

Comment: @SorenA when i start my computer, it gives me the image present in the question https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start . I press then alt+f2 to access to the terminal but I have to put first my login and password to gain access. unfortunatly i forgot them

Comment: @MahmoudAlBardan that was not what I asked ... before the system broke, how did you log in to the GUI if you have forgotte your login credentials (username and password) ?