# Can't get Lubuntu GUI working after switching from Gnome Desktop

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, lightdm, 20.10

I have an Ubuntu server running 20.10 and I was able to install Gnome Desktop Environment and that worked for me just fine but I recently uninstalled that to get Lubuntu instead and now I can't get the GUI to start up no matter what I have tried. I'm relatively new to Linux so I'm definitely frustrated so far but I don't want to have to reinstall a fresh ubuntu os just to get a GUI working again. I'm remotely connected to my ubuntu server through mobaxterm and I received no error messages when I installed any of these packages.

I have tried the following so far:

- Installed lightdm package to try to get the login screen to show up
- Installed lxdm and sddm as alternatives
- Updated packages to the latest version
- Tried the startx command and that did nothing
- Tried installing gnome again to go back to what worked

Here is a link to my startx log: https://0bin.net/paste/30naRWZw#1gTEBOb+f6ezPwDeUv0MN0Muk4MTJW9Rm57mRIPPnR5

Output from suggested commands:
https://0bin.net/paste/4EqYceyV#KX08E30DrXS6IADJXGGgwRCEfYBhhHxv4SV7m6z+AVl

Comment: Your pastebin is giving a 404 error. Please paste it into your question.

Comment: I believe uninstalling Gnome Desktop was the cause. Better to keep both desktops installed & switch to Lubuntu

Comment: @Keith5001 I did try to install gnome desktop again along with lubuntu. That was the last item in my list. I have both installed but can't get either one to work

Comment: @HengYe I updated the link to one that won't expire like the previous one

Comment: What packages, specifically, did you install to get the Lubuntu desktop?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I used the command apt get install lubuntu-desktop and I also tried removing it and readding it using tasksel and then selecting the lubuntu desktop option

Comment: @DarthVegan thanks for the info.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yw

Comment: I found this. It may help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start

Comment: @DarthVegan Could you add output of `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager; service *dm* status; ls -l /lib/systemd/system/*dm*; aptitude search '~i~Px-display-manager'; `

Comment: @Keith5001 I tried the suggested steps and that didn't work for me

Comment: @user.dz I included a new link to the output from the commands you had me run

Comment: @DarthVegan I could see two active, you may test stopping both/all then start only one. from console tty1-6. using `sudo systemctl stop/start/status/restart gdm/lxdm/sddm` share output if you see error in output. Another way to switch permanently is using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lxdm/gdm/sddm` but you need reboot. I suspect that having 2 DM's active is the issue here. So you may use systemd to disable service of DM that should be off.

Comment: @user.dz I did a purge on every dm I had installed except for gdm so I can try to go back to what was working before and did a reboot. I'm still not seeing the gui load

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs, you're still using gnome desktop manager.
Try this
sudo systemctl enable gdm3
And the query to your "startx", you must initialize ".xinitrc" in (~/.xinitrc) to start your desktop environment.
If the above command doesn't help you try making a xinitrc file.
Login to your server and then type,
vim .xinitrc then add this line in your file
"exec gnome-session" save and exit.
Restart your server and try again.
You can see more about xinitrc in the archwiki page.

Comment: I actually posted above how I disabled everything but gdm3 to try to go back to what was working. Also I took another look at my startx log and the error actually seems to be this line: [   907.243] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory

I'm guessing this means that I'm missing my graphics card drivers but I'm using a hosted server and not sure how to get the graphics drivers using Ubuntu

Comment: Did you use the command "sudo systemctl enable gdm3" ?

Comment: Yes I did that command

Comment: Do you still have lightdm installed on your system?? If you do you should replace gdm3 from above command and use lightdm

Comment: Did you read what I was saying? The error means I don't have a graphics driver installed

Comment: You do have a graphics driver installed. Make xinitrc file in your home directory and use vim editor. In your home directory type "vim .xinitrc" this will create a file. Inside that press "i" to type and then type "exec gnome-session" and then press "esc" and then type ":wq" this will save your file and exit you out from vim. Reboot your system and login then type startx. Hope this helps you.